# Designing Tests for Industry

Tags: writing, exams, assessment

I'm currently designing tests for people working in technology support. I am the current subject matter expert (SME) in my group for these topics.

The exam is essentially open-book multiple choice, 25 questions. I'm trying to design it so that they are instructed as they take the test, as they will have to take it multiple times if they do not pass the first time.

We have documentation, in fact I've written much of it, even if it does not get the attention it should.

I want to ensure I cover all bases for my questions.

As I write the exam, I am finding I want to ask questions about issues I have not yet documented, so I'll need to add those things to the documentation.

What is the best advice we have for constructing these sorts of exams?

Comment: Best advice about their use as tools of *instruction*, or of *assessment/evaluation*?

Comment: In this context, a combination, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You want general advice on constructing an exam? What are "these sorts" of exams? You mean exams that must be taken several times (same exam?) until the person passes? I read the question twice and I still don't understand the main point of the question. Could you rephrase it a bit to make it clearer?

Comment: What is the goal of the assessment? A test you take multiple times until you pass seems like an odd concept.

Comment: Odd or not, that's how we're certifying people as competent in various technologies. The penalty if you don't pass the first time is you have to take it again in the next test window. (And SME means Subject Matter Expert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments you state that the exam is used for certifying competency. This means that it should be extremely difficult for incompetent individuals to pass at the possible expense of failing competent individuals. Given the constraints of multiple choice, 25 questions, open book, and the ability to resit the exam, the definition of competency is important. You are going to need a very different type of test if competency means the ability look up information in a book versus the ability to know the information without using a book.

If the exam is testing the ability to look up information, then what you need to protect against is people memorizing the answers (i.e., abacda ...). Having a larger bank of questions, randomizing the order, and randomizing the answer order will decrease the ability to memorize the test. You also want to prevent people from taking the test home with them and probably want to impose a minimum wait between retests.

If competency means knowledge about the subject, your constraints are going to make it difficult. At a minimum you probably want to impose a time limit, but better would be to make the exam closed book. You should also test each concept with multiple questions and choose new question on each exam.

Comment: Thanks, since this is industry and they are support, they are used to having the information they need at their fingertips, although it would save them a lot of time to memorize the material in terms of lookups, they are really just being tested on their ability to be minimally competent on what is attempted to be a variety of related concepts and tasks on an entire subject.